# Error Installing pcaprub using GEM on Centos 5.9

Tags: centos, metasploit

I'm midprocess installing metasploit on my Centos 5.9 box. While performing the *bundle install* I get an error installing pcaprub which I've tried running solo as *gem install pcaprub* and recorded here. libpcap-devel-0.9.4-15.el5.i386.rpm is installed. I've lurked stackoverflow a great deal and sadly this is my first post. I'm sure to be missing something cornerstone to my issue with what logs I've posted so please don't hesitate to illuminate this.

```
gem install pcaprub
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pcaprub:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb

[*] Running checks for pcaprub code...
platform is i686-linux
checking for pcap_open_live() in -lpcap... yes
checking for pcap_setnonblock() in -lpcap... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling pcaprub.c
pcaprub.c: In function 'Init_pcaprub':
pcaprub.c:954: error: 'PCAP_ERROR' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:954: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
pcaprub.c:954: error: for each function it appears in.)
pcaprub.c:955: error: 'PCAP_ERROR_BREAK' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:956: error: 'PCAP_ERROR_NOT_ACTIVATED' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:957: error: 'PCAP_ERROR_ACTIVATED' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:958: error: 'PCAP_ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVICE' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:959: error: 'PCAP_ERROR_RFMON_NOTSUP' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:960: error: 'PCAP_ERROR_NOT_RFMON' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:961: error: 'PCAP_ERROR_PERM_DENIED' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:962: error: 'PCAP_ERROR_IFACE_NOT_UP' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:969: error: 'PCAP_WARNING' undeclared (first use in this function)
pcaprub.c:970: error: 'PCAP_WARNING_PROMISC_NOTSUP' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [pcaprub.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pcaprub-0.11.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pcaprub-0.11.3/ext/pcaprub/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 7):

I used the following command and it seemed to fix it so run

```
apt-get install libpcap-dev
```

after running that i was then able to use

```
gem install pcaprub
```

without any problems.

Comment: Works for my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact same issue and it took a while to figure out what was wrong.
I believe that the headers for libpcap are a little old if you install it using yum.

So, remove it and build it manually.

```
yum remove libpcap*
wget http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz
tar -xf libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz
cd libpcap-1.5.3
./configure
make
make install
```

Edit:  I also had to reinstall ncap to get everything to work.